# Is there a way to add centroids and spiders to this PCoA plot code?

Tags: r, centroid

New here, and to using R in general. I'm trying to modify a script for generating PCoA plots to include centroids and "spiders" (line segments connecting each sample data point to the centroid). Similar to the attached image.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dvpn.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjj3T.png

This is the code I've been using:

```
p.pcoa.wuniRM <- plot_ordination(ps2.prev_RM, ord.pcoa.wuniRM, color = "Location", axes = c(4,5)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(shape = Location)) +
  labs(title = "PCoA of wUniFrac Distances", color = "Location") +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=5), aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Is there an easy way to modify this script to get the centroids and spiders graphed, or do I need to find a different script all together?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `stat_ellipse()` function:

```
p +
 stat-ellipse()
```